# Can't scroll in a specific zone of my website

Tags: css

Could anybody help? I'll give you a link, you can scroll anywhere in the website but if your mouse is in the black zone, it zeems like you cannot scroll down... any idea ?

http://ge.aigginformatique.com

You can scroll on background, on the wrapper but you cannot on the ''content'' zone (black background)

Comment: Seems like your scroll plugin is interfering with the scroll event.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at your page, and found that there exists a `div` that looks like:

```
<div class="scroll  pad1" style="margin-top: 20px; overflow: hidden;">
```

Taking a look at the event listeners, I found a piece of code that is activated `onmousewheel` which somehow is preventing scrolling when the cursor is over this div.

I would recommend looking over your code (especially the JS) and fix any issues there.
If you don't understand what the code is doing, try removing the 'scroll' class. Note that this may have unintended side effects.

Comment: Probably there is a scrolling plug-in somewhere in there.

Comment: Yeah I didnt made this code, just had to fix it but found it, I had to put z-index : -1 on the #homepage and on the #container

Comment: Meh it's not working finaly... just found out that the content was not accessible anymore if I do that, can't click the buttons...

Comment: I suggest you try another way to organize your content.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are buttons for scrolling on that div that are hidden or off the screen. You've got several linked external style sheets that could be affecting this as well. Just skimming, the one called fancybox contains the line "scrolling:no;" but there could be other instances.